# Returning C structs by-value to Julia

Tags: c, struct, julia

I am trying to pass a C struct to Julia using `ccall`

Here is my file in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    float a;
    float b;
} TestStruct;

TestStruct getStruct() {
    TestStruct s = {3.0f, 5.0f};
    printf("Created struct a: %f b: %f\n", s.a, s.b);
    return s;
}
```

Then I compile this into a shared library to use with Julia.

Here is my Julia file:

```
immutable TestStruct
    a::Cfloat
    b::Cfloat
end

struct = ccall((:getStruct, "libteststruct"), TestStruct, ())
println("Got struct a: ", struct.a, " b: ", struct.b)
```

When I run this file I would expect to get

```
Created struct a: 3.000000 b: 5.000000
Got struct a: 3.0 b: 5.0
```

However, I am instead getting

```
Created struct a: 3.000000 b: 5.000000
Got struct a: 3.0 b: 0.0
```

`a` is always correct but `b` is always `0`.

This works when I use doubles in the struct instead of floats, but I need to use floats.

Thank you.

Comment: What platform and which version of Julia? (might be relevant)

Comment: I am using 64 bit Mac OS X Mavericks and Julia 0.3.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on Julia v0.3.x, `ccall` does not handle returning structs via the calling convention correctly. You can try changing the ccall usage to this:

```
struct_buffer = Array(TestStruct)
ccall((:getStruct, "libteststruct"), Void, (Ptr{TestStruct},), struct_buffer)
struct = struct_buffer[]
```

This issue may be fixed on Julia master (0.4-dev), so you can also try that and see how it goes.

Answer (score 5):

This works fine for me on Julia master (0.4-dev) -- on Windows to boot. Full by-value struct support was only recently [merged into master](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/7906). It might appear to (kind of) work on 0.3 but is not officially supported and should probably be an error.